# video app save .mp4 to camera roll

Tags: ios

i have a vidoe app that all she does is to play a single .mp4 file.
i want to save that file to camera roll in the iphone it will be played.
i already have the code but for some reason the video is not able to save.

no errors, nothing seems to be misplaced but still doesnt save.
i spend hours traying to solve that problem but no sucsses.
if someone can help me figure that out? please? pretty please?
here is the code for the save function...

```
- (IBAction)save{

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    // don't forget to link to the AssetsLibrary framework
    // and also #import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

    NSString *filePathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_name" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathString isDirectory:NO];

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:filePathURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:filePathURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            if (error) {
               // TODO: error handling

            } else {
                // TODO: success handling
            }
        }];
    }
    }
```

Comment: please I don't have any idear and it keep my project stuck. So if someone can help me with this I will be gratefull

Comment: That question is already a week since it was asked..and still no answer??? what this site is for? just to publish codes? or try to fix problem...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no one has answered this earlier. If you still need help, this should work for you:

```
- (IBAction)save{
    NSString *filePathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_name" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathString isDirectory:NO];

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([filePathURL relativePath], self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void) video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
    if (!error){
        // Saved successfully
    } else {
        // Error saving
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, but it doesnt work...it doesnt save to photo gallery...dont know why???

Comment: If you're testing this on a device, make sure your app has permission to access the photos. Also, is there an error? Using my code, in the // Error saving section, add an NSLog or a breakpoint and see if it stops there.